# Delete wrong values from an array with help of panda

Tags: python, database

I have a problem with my data, there are a number of displacement in different times. But unfortunately in some cases for one time I have 2 or 3 different displacements, of which only the higher value is acceptable.

I used Panda and now I have all the values in my paython code and change them to a 2X2 array.

Acctually I need to write an algorithm to find all the duplicates t and check their x and delete the whole line if x is lower than in other cases.

I would really appreciate for any ideas.

t  x

1  2

2  3

3  4

4  5

5  5

3  3

1  1

7  5

I have written an example. I need here for the "Time" equal to 3 and 1 to delete the whole line that has a lower x.

Comment: Please include a small example to clarify your question

Comment: It would be appreciate if you put some code to clarify your question

Comment: @Cobra I Wrote an Example

Comment: @Kang I Wrote an Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have `pandas dataframe` such as :

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {'t':[1,2,3,4,5,3,1,7],
              'x':[2,3,4,5,5,3,1,5]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

you can select `column: t` equals 3  and 1, as following :

```
dataframe.loc[(dataframe['t'] == 3| 1)].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Also, you can select `column: t` does not equals 3  and 1, as following :

```
dataframe.loc[(dataframe['t'] != 3| 1)].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I need to write an algorithm to find all the duplicates and check their x and delete the whole line if x is lower than in other cases.

Comment: But it is really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you  want the minimum 'x' for each t, as long as that value of t appears more than once in the data?

Comment: actually I want to keep the maximum value of t and delete the other line. If there is more than one value for the same t  @Cobra